# How can I avoid using a default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

this is a question for my current class assignment. I need to use only one constructor in my code, and I can't quite figure out how to do it.

```
class test {
  public:
     test(int x, int y, int z);
     (...)
  private:
     int x,y,z;
}

test::test(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0){
  this -> x = x;
  this -> y = y;
  this -> z = z;
}

int main (){
  test test1, test2(1,2,3)
  (...)
}
```

Currently, it won't compile because it says I don't have a matching function call for test1. I was pretty sure that using the int x = 0 as the parameter set a default one...

Comment: You have `test1` twice. And default parameter values need to be in the declaration, not definition.

Answer (score 0):

Default paramter should values go into the declaration, not definition.

```
class test {
  public:
     test(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0);
     (...)
  private:
     int x,y,z;
}
```

And the definition:

```
test::test(int x, int y, int z){
  this -> x = x;
  this -> y = y;
  this -> z = z;
}
```

While you're at it, you can get into the good habit of using constructor initializer lists:

```
test::test(int x, int y, int z):
    x(x), y(y), z(z)
{
}
```

Comment: It's allowed to put the default arguments in the definition and not the declaration, but it's terrible style, because things related to the interface should be put in the declaration.

Comment: Clarified a little. Should ≠ must, but I'm not sure if the intent is obvious enough.

Comment: @BrianBi: You can't in this case ([dcl.fct.default]/6), although only Clang diagnoses it.